# Get Unique Identifier in BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery

**Use case**

I need a stable Unique Identifier in a BigQuery table which is inserted into by Google. Thus I can not insert a UUID or similiar along with each row entry (but this is exactly what I need). I am aware of BigQuery's `GENERATE_UUID()` however this would return a new UUID on each query, which is not desired.

**My question**

How can I get an unique identifier for each row in a BigQuery table which is stable across multiple queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use combination of [TO_JSON_STRING()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string) with one of [hash functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#hash-functions) like [FARM_FINGERPRINT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#farm_fingerprint)

```
SELECT FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t)), *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Comment: Works as expected, genius!